# Laravel Sail failed to run artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have successfully install Laravel with Sail, the app is just fine, I can run it using `sail up`. however I am unable to migrate the database, everytime I run `sail artisan migrate` the following error thrown.

```
There is no existing directory at "/home/dariel/www/2021/nsmart/storage/logs" and it could not be created: Permission denied

  at vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:172
    168▕             set_error_handler([$this, 'customErrorHandler']);
    169▕             $status = mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
    170▕             restore_error_handler();
    171▕             if (false === $status && !is_dir($dir)) {
  ➜ 172▕                 throw new \UnexpectedValueException(sprintf('There is no existing directory at "%s" and it could not be created: '.$this->errorMessage, $dir));
    173▕             }
    174▕         }
    175▕         $this->dirCreated = true;
    176▕     }

      +10 vendor frames 
  11  [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions::handleException()
```

I am stuck at this point, any help would be appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
php artisan route:clear;
php artisan config:clear;
php artisan cache:clear;
sail artisan migrate;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error states: There is **no existing directory** at `/home/dariel/www/2021/nsmart/storage/logs` **Permission denied**. So you have to run `mkdir /home/dariel/www/2021/nsmart/storage/logs` and done...

Remember to have `storage` folder accesible for the process running your `artisan` command, it needs to use any folder inside `storage`.

And, if I am not wrong, `sail up` will give you an error, so that is why it is trying to do something in the `logs` folder.

Comment: unfortunatelly there is a directory called `logs` inside that `/home/dariel/www/2021/nsmart/storage` folder.

Comment: @DarielPratama is it accesible by the user running the `artisan` command ? do a test and run `chmod 777 storage` and see if giving full access to it will fix it

Comment: yep, I already run `chmod 777 storage -R` but still error

Comment: The error is **Permission denied** so it is not accesible by the process

Comment: did you run these commands `php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear`